# Unhide list upon clicking on promoted link

Tags: promoted-links

I would like to reveal/unhide custom list `1` when I click on promoted link `A`, on the same page.

Additionally, when I click on a promoted link `B`, O would like to hide custom list `1'` and reveal custom list `2` in the same position as list `1`.

I am using SharePoint 2013

How can this be done?

Comment: Does it have to be the same page? You could go easy on yourself and just create 2 identical pages.

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate your requirement.
 It is possible to make tile (promoted link) visible to a particular group in SharePoint .